# Use GStreamer with Qt Android Target

Tags: android, c++, qt, gstreamer

I have the following, which compiles for the desktop target.

```
LIBS += -lgstreamer-1.0
```

However, this fails to compile for the Android target. Why is this? I downloaded the GStreamer for Android on their website—though I believe that to just be a JNI interface for the same package.

`PKGCONFIG` doesn't work either, but instead makes it not work for even the desktop target (the error was something to do with the QML engine in this case, not sure why)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the .a files for GStreamer, put libgstreamer-1.0.a in {project directory}/lib/android, and then in the Qt .pro file,

```
LIBS    += -L$$PWD/lib/android/ -lgstreamer-1.0 -lglib-2.0
```